# Issue Parsing XML Documnet with Linq.Xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is NOT a question about the NullReferenceException. It is a question about why the statement shown would be throwing one and what is wrong with it.

I am attempting to parse a small XML document using Linq.Xml and am getting a Null Reference exception when attempting to create a list of objects from a Linq query

```
            _columnDefs = (from def in fileDef.Descendants("columndef")
                       select new ColumnDef ()
                        { 
                            Name = def.Attribute("Name").Value,
                            Type = def.Attribute("Type").Value,
                            Required = bool.Parse(def.Attribute("Required").Value),
                            Default = def.Attribute("Default").Value
                        }).ToList<ColumnDef>();
```

The code here fails with a NullReferenceException as seen here

[image]

I'm having trouble trying to figure out if the new ColumDef object is the issue or something else. If it is the new ColumnDef then why is the "new" operator not creating an instance of the object?

_columnDefs is defined as `_columnDefs = new List<ColumnDef>();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Every `columndef`'s node contains the attributes `Name`,`Type`,`Required`,`Default`?

Comment: @coderoipo - They do not. I was under the impression that it would fill the string variable ('Default' in this case is an optional Attribute) with null and leave it at that. What would be the best way to solve this issue? Can I actually write a conditional statement inside the Linq statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debugger view shows that the current item has no `Default` attribute. You can use `default = (string)def.Attribute("Default")` to have the property set to `null` if the attribute does not exist.

Comment: If he is using C# 6 he could also achieve the same thing (and maybe give more of a hint to the reader that he knows this value may be null) by using the null propagation operator - def.Attribute("Default")?.Value

Comment: Thanks to @coderoipo, Martin and TVOHM for their responses. coderoipo got me started in the right direction for searching for an answer and Martin and TVOHM pointed out what I clearly missed. Thanks again!